# Accessing this from Inside EventListener Inside Angular2 Singleton Service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to watch a window event to update a variable in a Singleton service. I gave up on using @HostListener because it didn't seem to work and I read somewhere that it is incompatible with services. Why does the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

declare let window;

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
    private progress = new BehaviorSubject(0); // edited according to aluans recommendation
    progressObservable$ = this.progress.asObservable();

    constructor() {
        window.addEventListener('progress', () => {
            this.progress.next(window.sharedService.progress);
        });
    }
}
```

Generate this console error:

Uncaught TypeError: _this.progress.next is not a function

**Solved** It ended up being a problem because I was over-riding the progress variable on the window object which I attached the service to.

Comment: Not directly related but please don't write code like `new BehaviorSubject<any>(0)`. Write `new BehaviorSubject(0)`, letting the compiler correctly infer the type as `BehaviorSubject<number>` instead of overpowering it with a vacuous, pointless annotation that increases verbosity and reduces quality.

Comment: thx.. Im trying to go pro here. really, thanks for the tip though

Comment: After taking a look at this a bit more, I am slightly perplexed. I see you are referencing `window.sharedService.progress`, but you never assign anything to `window.sharedService`. That is probably good, as you should not be sharing state by attaching it to global variables, but it is also a failure point.

Comment: I suspect you want something like `window.addEventListener('progress', ({ total }) => { this.progress.next(total); });` but that also seems rather suspect. What is responsible for raising events?

Comment: Hi Aluan... I updated my response with ***Solved*** at the bottom.. it ended up being because I was accessing the progress variable outside of the class